# If $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are independent Bernoulli random variables, calculate $E[S_{\tau_{2}}]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ be independent Bernoulli random variables. $P(X_{i}=1)=p$, $P(X_{i}=0)=q=1-p$. We denote $S_{n}=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$. There are $\tau_{1}=\min \{n: X_{n}=1\}$ and $\tau_{2}=\min \{n: X_{n}=X_{n-1}=1\}$. How to calculate $E[S_{\tau_{2}}]$?

I've tried through the total expectation formula. I got

$$E[S_{\tau_{2}}]=\frac2p+\frac{E[S_{\tau_{2}-\tau_{1}}]+1}{1-p}$$

But it is not clear how to proceed further.

A similar question for $\tau_{3}=\min \{n: X_{n}=X_{n-1}=X_{n-2}=1\}$. How to calculate $E[S_{\tau_{3}}]$?

Comment: Have you tried finding the distributon function of $\tau_2$?

Comment: From the first sentence, it looks like $n$ is a constant, the number of the finitely many given random variables. Then we see $n$ also in the $\min$-expressions. Please make clear what are $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$, $\tau_3$. (Possibly with some other index $j$ from $1$ to $n$. Then do we consider $j-1$ cyclically? Or let $j$ in this case run only from $2$ to $n$?)

Comment: Also, the question has not too much context, please provide more... The try is only sketched without any details. (Compared to the work shown in the one existing answer, please try to offer more. What happens for instance for $n=2$ and/or $n=3$? Why is this question interesting / in which context did it appear?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be I'm misunderstading something, but:

Let's divide the sequence $(X_i)$ into runs of $t\in \{0,1, 2\cdots\}$ consecutive zeros followed by a one. Let's call $Y_i$ the lengths of these subsequence.

Then $Y_i$ are [iid geometric (starting at $1$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), i.e. $P(Y_i=y)= p q^{y-1}$.

And the event $S_{\tau_{2}} =s$ corresponds to $\{Y_s=1 \wedge 1<k<s \implies Y_k >1 \}$

Then  $E[S_{\tau_{2}}] = 1 + \frac{1}{p}$

Answer (score 1):

Sketch (almost solution):

Put $$A_n = \{ \text{ in  a set $\{ X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ there's no two consecutive units \}} \}$$ $$= \{ \not \exists 1 \le i  \le n-1: X_i = X_{i+1} \} = \{ \tau_2 > n\}.$$
Put $a_n = P(A_n, X_n = 0 )$ and $b_n = P(B_n, X_n=1)$. We have
$$b_{n+1} = P(A_{n+1}, X_{n+1} = 1) = P(A_{n+1}, X_n = 0, X_{n+1} = 1) +  P(A_{n+1}, X_n = 1, X_{n+1} = 1)$$
$$ = P(A_{n}, X_n = 0, X_{n+1} = 1) + 0 = P(A_{n}, X_n = 0) P(X_{n+1} = 1) = \frac{a_n}2,$$
$$a_{n+1} = P(A_{n+1}, X_{n+1} = 0) = P(A_{n+1}, X_n = 0, X_{n+1} = 0) +  P(A_{n+1}, X_n = 1, X_{n+1} = 0)$$
$$ = P(A_{n}, X_n = 0, X_{n+1} = 0) +  P(A_{n}, X_n = 1, X_{n+1} = 0)=$$
$$ = P(A_{n}, X_n = 0)P(X_{n+1} = 0) +  P(A_{n}, X_n = 1)P( X_{n+1} = 0)=$$
$$ = a_n \frac12 + b_n \frac12 = \frac{a_n + b_n}2.$$
Thus
\begin{cases} b_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}2, \\ a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}2. \end{cases}
We have $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}2 = \frac{a_n + \frac12 a_{n-1}}2$, i.e. $4a_{n+1} = 2a_n + a_{n-1}$. Hence $a_n = \frac{C_1}{2^n} \cos(\frac{\pi n}{3}) +  \frac{C_2}{2^n} \sin(\frac{\pi n}{3})$ and $b_{n+1} = a_n$. It's easy to find $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ and hence to find $C_1$, $C_2$ and $a_n$, $b_n$. Finally $$E \tau_2 = \sum_{n \ge 0} P(\tau_2 > n) = \sum_{n \ge 0} P(A_n) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \big( P(A_n, X_n = 0) + P(A_n, X_n = 1) \big) = \sum_{n \ge 0} (a_n + b_n).  $$
As $\frac{a_n}{2^{-n}}$ and $\frac{b_n}{2^{-n}}$ are $O(1)$ we have $E \tau_2 < \infty$.

You can find $E \tau_3$ in the same way but with bigger amount of calculations.